# how do i know what line segments and polygons are inside the polygon in openlayers-3?

Tags: openlayers-3

I am trying to create an application where I have 3 layers.

1. Background layer (OSM)
2. Layer - 1 (which has only Line)
3. Layer - 2 (which has only Polygon)

My layer - 1 and Layer - 2 are invisible and when I draw a polygon in the background layer I want only the lines and polygons (from layer 1 and layer 2) be visible inside the polygon that i have drawn.

Can anyone suggest if it is possible using OL3?

Cheers

Comment: You could show what is done so far.

Comment: Do you want to show the full lines and polygons that fit within the digitised polygon. Or do you want to show just the piece of them intersecting the digitised polygon? And also, do the lines and polygons should be copletely within the digitised polygon or any interact (partially in, jsut crossing etc.) would be of interest?

Comment: I want to show all the lines and polygons that are inside the digitized polygon. I have to show the partial polygon or line too not the only ones that are completely inside. I have done nothing so far just loaded the layers in openlayers. I am trying to figure it out how to do this.

Comment: Anything to help me @pavlos?

Comment: But you have to start. Take the [examples](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/) and dive into them, create a jsfiddle and we can see where you are and what you need.

Comment: @Rooney now it's your time to say something. Did you get your solution?

Comment: I haven't have time to solve this issue as I was in holidays and I am currently setting up the layers in geoserver. As soon as I do that I will post my solution here thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Jonatas sais you have to start and we have to help you afterwards, if we have the time and mood to do it. So the message is "HELP TO GET HELPED".

Anyway, today I am in a good mood and I have some spare time.

So for your case and as long as you want to get back the intersections you need to use the [JSTS topology](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts) suite. There is also the [TURF.js](http://turfjs.org/) library for such actions but I am not familiar with it. So I ll give a solution using JSTS.

1. Declare you line and polygon layers and asign a style with 0 alpha chanel so be invisible on map. (within the supplied fiddle I have used 0.2 for alpha chanel so be little bit of visisble for testing purposes)
2. Create a `dragbox` interaction to use for you user to draw box
3. Select features from both layers that fall within your dragbox
4. Use the JSTS library to find the intersections of lines , polygons and the draw box
5. Create a new vector layer with full visibility and place the intersecting features

here is your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/oxsffy9e/)

Comment: Nice fiddle example, I suggest you put some links of the given utilities.